# How to get a list of String from Dom4j Node.selectObject or Node.selectNodes

Tags: xml, xpath, dom4j

Hope you have a good day.

The Dom4j javadoc form **Node.selectObject(String xpathExpression)** says the following:

*...The object returned can either be a List of one or more Node instances or a scalar object like a **String** or a Number instance depending on the XPath expression.*

However when I try to get a list of String on this piece of xml:

```
<root>
...
    <level1>
        <property>pro1</property>
        <property>pro1</property>
        <property>pro1</property>
    <level1>
...
</root>
```

with the following code:

```
List result = document.selectObject("/root/level1/property/text()")
```

I get a list of **org.dom4j.tree.DefaultText** objet. Of course I can iterate on the list but I yould like to know if there is a way to get a list of String.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Introduction

> An expression is evaluated to yield an
>   object, which has one of the following
>   four basic types:
>
> - node-set (an unordered collection of    nodes without duplicates)
> - boolean (true or false)
> - number (a floating-point number)
> - string (a sequence of UCS characters)

So, no sequence of `xs:string` in XPath 1.0

In XPath 2.0 there is a sequence data type, of course...

Comment: I'm using xpath 2.0. I don't understand your answer. Even if an expression is evaluated to yield and object of the described type, Dom4j Api should return a list of string isn't it.

Comment: @Periworks: If you are selecting XML nodes the result should be a `List` of `Node` from http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.4/apidocs/org/dom4j/Node.html#selectObject(java.lang.String) . Also do note that this method is deprecated in favor of `evaluate` and there is no indication that a dom4j interface can work with an XPath 2.0 engine