# How to return array with XPath?

Tags: xml, parsing, bash, xpath

I was wondering if XPath could return an array of value.

I have someting like this :

```
<Cities>
    <City>Paris</City>
    <City>Lyon</City>
    <City>Marseille</City>
</Cities>
```

And I'd like to get an array of this form ['Paris', 'Lyon', 'Marseille'].

I am using the xpath UNIX utility.

Any idea ?

Comment: It's not exact but it's the same [How to get a list of String from Dom4j Node.selectObject or Node.selectNodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628647/how-to-get-a-list-of-string-from-dom4j-node-selectobject-or-node-selectnodes). If you want a sequence data type result you must use XPath 2.0

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and solution. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to post-processing the output of:

```
xpath -q -e '//City/text()' inputfile
```

which is:

```
Paris
Lyon
Marseille
```

in any number of ways, including:

```
xpath -q -e '//City/text()' inputfile |
    awk 'BEGIN {sq = "\047"; OFS = sq "," sq}
         {a[$1] = NR}
         END {
             printf "[" sq; 
             for (i in a) {
                 printf "%s%s", d, i; d = OFS};
             print sq "]"
         }'
```

which gives the output:

```
['Lyon','Marseille','Paris']
```

you can use my modified version of `xpath`. Since it's a simple Perl script, I modified it so you have more control over the formatting of the output. With my version, you can do:

```
xpath -q -b "[" -p "'" -i "," -s "'" -a "]"$'\n' -e '//City/text()'
```

to get the desired output. Here is the usage message:

```
Usage:
xpath [options] -e query [-e query...] [filename...]

        If no filenames are given, supply XML on STDIN.
        You must provide at least one query. Each supplementary
        query is done in order, the previous query giving the
        context of the next one.

        Options:

        -q quiet        Only output the resulting PATH
        -b before       use before instead of nothing.
        -p prefix       use prefix instead of nothing.
        -s suffix       use suffix instead of linefeed.
        -i infix        use infix instead of nothing.
        -a after        use after instead of nothing.
```

You can [download my version here](http://netstrata.com/files/xpath.txt).

Answer (score 2):

**This XPath expression**:

```
/*/*/text()
```

selects exactly the three wanted text nodes.

**You can use it with an array-like notation**:

```
/*/*/text()[1]
```

selects the text-node

```
"Paris"
```

,

```
/*/*/text()[2]
```

selects the text-node

```
"Lyon"
```

,

```
/*/*/text()[3]
```

selects the text-node

```
"Marseille"
```

**If you want just the string value of any of these text nodes, use** (for example):

```
string(/*/*/text()[2])
```

The result of evaluating this XPath expression is the string

```
"Lyon"
```

Answer (score 1):

i know that in .Net  you can do it in `xmlDocument`. `xDoc.SelectNodes("//City");` it gives you a list of nodes and for each node you can do `NODE.FirstChild.Value` to get the names.